# Spying on "mandatory" messages in Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-amqp

I have been using the Spring AMQP's implementation of "mandatory" messages present since 1.5 ([AMQP-507](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-507)). Now, I would like to "spy" on these messages for a number of purposes, but it seems that I can't really have something other than the intended consumers receiving those messages (as that would count as a delivery and the sender would thus not be notified). Do I have any alternative (provided either by RabbitMQ itself or Spring AMQP) to "duplicate" these messages to another queue without messing with EIP (SmartProxy or Wiretap)?

(Of course, all my queues are declared as "auto-delete" so that this works as expected, and that's what makes this harder to accomplish.)

Answer (score 1):

**On the client side**

You could use an interceptor. For example if you are using `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` from the `spring-rabbit` project you could use an `Advice` using the `adviceChain` or a message post processor `MessagePostProcessor`.

For example [using the example given on the main page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/)

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
container.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(new MessagePostProcessor() {
                @Override
                public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
                    return null;
                }
            });
```

**On the rabbitmq side**

There is the [firehose](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) hammer. You will receive a copy of ALL the message in a given queue.

If you are using a direct exchange you could change its type to a topic exchange and bind your copy queue using the routing key "*", but it will not be compatible with the "mandatory" semantics".